# EM Algorithm Derivation, Discrete Case

Tags: expectation-maximization

Just wanted to ask whether the following derivation is correct:

Suppose $X$ is a vector of observed random variables, $Z$ is a vector of unobserved random variables and $\theta$ is a vector of parameters. Let $S$ be the set of values $Z$ could take on; we'll assume this is discrete. We'll also assume the following are known

$f(x|z,\theta)$ = the probability density function of X given Z and theta
$P(Z=z|\theta)$ = the probability that $Z=z$ given $\theta$

The likelihood function I want is

$\prod_{z\in S}[f(x|z,\theta)P(Z=z|\theta)]^{1_{Z=z}}$

Taking the logarithm:

$\sum_{z\in S}1_{Z=z}[\log f(x|z,\theta)+\log P(Z=z|\theta)]$

Now suppose I'm performing the EM algorithm and my current estimate of $\theta$ is $\theta^{(n)}$. Then I need to apply $E_{Z|\theta^{(n)},x}$ to the above expression. This gives:

$\sum_{z\in S}P(Z=z|\theta^{(n)})[\log f(x|z,\theta)+\log P(Z=z|\theta)]$

That is the expression I need to maximize with respect to $\theta$ in the M step.

Is that correct, or did I make a mistake somethere? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your derivation looks correct. Just a minor clarification in the final expression -

In the expression, $\sum_{z\in S}P(Z=z|x,\theta^{(n)})[\log f(|z,\theta)+\log P(Z=z|\theta)]$, the term $P(Z=z|x,\theta^{(n)})$ would be computed in Expectation step; hence, during the maximization step, it is treated as constant value. In the M-step, derivatives are computed for only the terms within the bracket.